# Do I need to compile separately included header files from another direcotry?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, include, linker-errors

I'm working on a project (hangman.c) and I want to include a module I wrote from another directory (quicksort.h). Here is the top of my hangman.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "../quicksort/quicksort.h"
```

I've been running this command:

```
clang -o hangman hangman.c
```

And i get this error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/hangman-3292ab.o: in function `append_and_order':
hangman.c:(.text+0x26c): undefined reference to `quicksort'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I compile them separately and link them together manually with

```
gcc -c hangman.c 
gcc -c ../quicksort/quicksort.c
gcc -o hangman hangman.o quicksort.o
```

(As corrected). And that works, but isn't the point of #include to do this automatically at the preprocessing stage?

Comment: you forgot to add quicksort.c to clang (same as for gcc). You do not need 2 first commands for gcc either.

Comment: `#include` is a preprocessor directive; it has absolutely nothing to do with linking, so don't expect it to fix link-time errors regarding missing/undefined  references. Unrelated, if those three commands all actually succeed it suggests you have *two* copies of `quicksort.c` on your file system; you had best resolve that scenario lest you find yourself back here asking why changes to code seemingly have no effect.

Comment: I thought that if the preprocessor pasted the contents of quicksort into hangman.c then it wouldn't need to link anything. It would all be self contained. That's how they taught what include does. I wrote the last commands wrong, not how I ran it. It should be hangman.o quicksort.o

Comment: The preprocessor pastes the text of whatever file you tell it to. And just that. The headers don't contain the definitions of the functions. If you need those definitions, pasting header text isn't enough.